# How to get a JSON Object from my database with PHP

Tags: php, json, database

I'm a beginner in `PHP` development, and I have a problem with the `JSON` output .

My `JSON` ( the element take in my database) start with a Square bracket ( `JSON` Array) like this:

```
[{"Ut_Email":"prova@randomemail.it"}].
```

Unfortunately, I want to see only the `JSON` Object , like this:

```
{"Ut_Email":"prova@randomemail.it"}
```

Is it possible?

This is my `PHP` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <body>
  <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","name","")
   or die("Impossibile connettersi al server MySQL.\n"); 
   //select the db
   mysql_select_db("name")
   or die("Impossibile aprire il database.\n");
  //create the query
  $sql=mysql_query("select Ut_Email from utente"); 
  /*Il metodo "mysql_fetch_assoc" restituisce un array in base alla query 
  fatta e incrementa il dato*/
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    //inseriamo tutto nella variabile output
    $output[]=$row;
    /*print the json object*/
    print(json_encode($output)); 
  //close the connection
  mysql_close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just dont loop and get rid of the output array:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select Ut_Email from utente"); 
if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   print(json_encode($row)); 
}
```

Comment: But so i see only one element, not all.
I solved with your solution but using the while in place of the if.
Thanks

Comment: so you need an array, you said you dont want to see the brackets, and thats what this code will do

Comment: i need to visualize all the element, but without the "[" "]", to use this with my android application. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Luke if you show me your java code, I will show you how to parse it

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the result from the query to an array so the json output includes the square brackets (which is array in javascript). If you want to output only one row, you can remove the while loop and just call `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);` and then use json_encode on `$row`. If you need more than one row to be returned, you will need the array or else it isn't valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Since your SQL query is fetching users without any filter, it is reasonable to expect that the result of that query has more than one result. Based on this I would say to keep the loop and loose the assignment to `$output` **unless you plan to use it later, then keep it just as it is**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <body>
        <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","name","")
        or die("Impossibile connettersi al server MySQL.\n"); 
        //select the db
        mysql_select_db("name")
        or die("Impossibile aprire il database.\n");
        //create the query
        $sql=mysql_query("select Ut_Email from utente"); 

        /*Il metodo "mysql_fetch_assoc" restituisce un array in base alla query 
        fatta e incrementa il dato*/
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
        {
            //inseriamo tutto nella variabile output
            $output[]=$row; // OK if you plan to use $output later, otherwise unnecessary.

            /*print the json object*/
            print( json_encode( $row ) ); // Just print the $row testing
        }

        //close the connection
        mysql_close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I solved like this:

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
     print( json_encode( $row ) );
    }